# How to use Bluetooth in Android emulator?

Tags: android

I want to create an application based on bluetooth operation in android.I am using the following code

```
 BluetoothAdapter adapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

the adapter is returning null value, which means the android emulator is not having bluetooth capability. i am using android 2.1 the latest version of android.Anybody knows how to use the bluetooth from android emulator, please help me.

Comment: This answer seems to work....

http://stackoverflow.com/a/22604411/1285325

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can't. The emulator does not support Bluetooth, as mentioned in the SDK's docs and on several other places.

And you already discovered this yourself: "the adapter is returning null value, which means the android emulator is not having bluetooth capability"

Answer (score 16):

You can install the image from http://www.android-x86.org/  into a virtual machine (e.g. VMWare), find out it's IP address, connect manually using

```
adb connect <IP of VM>
```

And then launch your project from Eclipse by setting a "Manual" deployment target in your Debug/Run configuration. Bluetooth works in this Virtual Machine at least on my Macbook and it's reported to work with a couple of other bluetooth chipsets.

Comment: If I were to connect a bluetooth dongle to my system, is there any way to use bluetooth via that?

Comment: If you have a USB dongle and ensure that it's passed through and connected to the virtual machine, I'd assume it works, yes.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to run bluetooth aap on emulator.as there is no support for bluetooth on emulator. look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html Emulator Limitations

In this release, the limitations of the emulator include:

- No support for placing or receiving actual phone calls. You can simulate phone calls (placed and received) through the emulator
  console, however.
- No support for USB connections
- No support for camera/video capture (input).
- No support for device-attached headphones
- No support for determining connected state
- No support for determining battery charge level and AC charging state
- No support for determining SD card insert/eject
- No support for Bluetooth

Answer (score 2):

Q. `Bluetooth doesn't work on my device. How should I debug?`

A. First step - read the logs (`adb logcat`)! In particular look for ERROR or WARNING level messages regarding Bluetooth.

Andoird uses Bluez, which comes with some very useful debugging tools. Here are some examples, in the rough order I use to debug BT.

```
hciconfig -a  # print BT chipset address and features. Useful to
# check if you can communicate with your BT chipset.

hcidump -XVt  # print live HCI UART traffic.
hcitool scan  # scan for local devices. Useful to check if RX/TX works.
l2ping ADDRESS  # ping another BT device. Useful to check if RX/TX works.
sdptool records ADDRESS # request the SDP records of another BT device.
```

You can install the bluetooth plugin from http://www.android-videos.blogspot.com/ Once the installation is done you can use bluetooth with the Emulator.

Comment: Link to videos does not have link for bluetooth plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently planning a tool that is capable of emulating Bluetooth over TCP/IP under Linux (will be released freely under GPL).

This should be the solution when not having a real Bluetooth device (e.g. you want to simulate a connection between two emulated Android-x86 or Linux machines).

Maybe when compiling for Linux-ARM instead of Linux-x86 it will run in the Emulator, too.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It should have been a comment, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree, right now the emulator does not support Bluetooth.

To compile Android with Bluetooth support enabled, add the following line to `BoardConfig.mk`.

```
BOARD_HAVE_BLUETOOTH := true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can but you will need to run your app on an Android inside a VirtualBox or VMWare image. For more infos, see here (tutorial is for Bluetooth LE, but it works just the same with other Bluetooth versions): [Bluetooth Low Energy on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27712017/1121352)

Answer (score 0):

The emulator doesnt support bluetooth as mentioned in the sdk's docs. You have to check this in real device..

And you got error Bluetooth binder is null. it means emulator does not have bluetooth capability.