# What's the prognosis for Bluetooth device support in the emulator?

Tags: android, bluetooth, emulation

It's pretty clear that the current emulator does not provide Bluetooth support.  While there appears to be a third-party emulator available that might work it seems to come with warnings about bugs that tend to suggest that I might be better off spending my energies elsewhere.  Does anyone know of progress, and perhaps even a target, for getting Bluetooth support built into the device emulator in the Android SDK Tools?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround available though that lets you utilize your computers bluetooth and still have the benefits of debugging on the spot, so to say.

You can install a virtual machine android and have it use your onboard bluetooth. There is a readily installed image for this available, just google it. You can then have adb connect to this device as you would with any other real or virtual device, it is also described if you look it up on the net. I hope this helps.

Still, build in bluetooth support is something I would love the emulator to get enhanced by.

Comment: can you add links of where this is and then I will upvote you. yeah you can google it but maybe we aren't using the right keywords or same ones you did.

Comment: @JPM: Check this other answer on another related thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/4983743/186880