# Bluetooth is not detected in my system but is in phone

Tags: android

I am working on a project related to Bluetooth. I wrote this sample code to detect Bluetooth in a device.

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if(bluetooth!=null)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "gfvhfh", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This code is working perfectly in my phone and displaying the text in toast, but in my system it's not showing anything. I am using a external Bluetooth adapter for my system.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that by system you mean **emulator**, in that case it is 100% normal.
You can't use Bluetooth on the emulator as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175076/how-to-use-bluetooth-in-android-emulator).
Please check before asking a question that it hasn't been asked before!