# is there any possibility to execute bluetooth chat application in emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

i got the sample code of bluetooth chat application.from here.
is it possible to execute the application in emulator?
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

Comment: u better see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175076/how-to-use-bluetooth-in-android-emulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No You can not test it on emulator. You have to purchase a physical device.

Refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#limitations).

Comment: @venkat, I think you can make this as answer; so for others it would be helpful.