# error on emulator of eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth, communication

I'm getting following error on emulator.I'm posting codes which is for communicating with paired Bluetooth device.I'm able to connect the Bluetooth device which is non Android,but when I add code for communication (read/write) it gives an error on emulator.Please suggest if anybody knows the solution.I'm new in Android.

```
                  "Unfortunately, App has stopped "
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

Button scanButton,connectButton,sendButton; 
EditText commands;
TextView out;

UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT=0;
private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
public static ArrayList<Object> BondedDeviceList;

BluetoothSocket mmSocket,mm;
BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
OutputStream mmOutputStream;
InputStream mmInputStream;
//private static String address = "00:06:66:04:62:73";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.example.bluecomm.R.layout.activity_list_item);
    scan();

}


public void scan() 
{
    scanButton = new Button(this);
    scanButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    scanButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 

      {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) 
        {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "device not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        }
        else
        {

          if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) 
           {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MAKING YOUR DEVICE ENABLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
           }else{}

           pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
           if(pairedDevices==null)
            {
            //No Bonded Devices 
             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Bonded Devices", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                   toast.show();
             }
             else
             {
             if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) 
             {
                // Loop through paired devices
              for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) 
              {
               if(device.getName().equals("RN_BS-6273"))
                {
                   mmDevice = device;
                   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                   toast.show();
                   break;
                }else{}

              }
             }else{}
            }
        }
        }
      });
    connectdevice();
}


public void connectdevice() 
{
    connectButton = new Button(this);
    connectButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    connectButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
      {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
       {

         try
         {

         mm = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);  
         Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "uuid assigned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast1.show();
         }
         catch(IOException e)
         {}
         mmSocket=mm;
         run();
     }

      public void run()
      {
          try
          {
              mmSocket.connect();
             // mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
              //mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();
              if(mmSocket.isConnected())
              {
              Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "device is connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast1.show();
              }
              else{}
             /* try
              {
                  int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                  if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                  {
                      byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                      mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                  }else{}*/
              }
          catch (IOException closeException) 
            { }
            return;
          }

      });


    send();
}



public void send() 
{
    commands=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.icon);
    sendButton = new Button(this);
    sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
      {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = mmSocket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInputStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutputStream = tmpOut;
            write();
        }

       public void write()
       {
        try
         {
       String msg = commands.getText().toString();
       msg += "\n";
       mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
      // mmInputStream.read();
         }
         catch (IOException close) 
         { 


              try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Socket closing....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
              toast1.show();

             } 

             return;
          }
      });
    }



  }
```

activity_list_item.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="Scan" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
android:text="Connect" />
<EditText
android:id="@+id/icon"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/button2"/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/button3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
android:text="Send" />
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/data"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
android:text="DATA:"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a BluetoothAdapter with an emulator. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175076/how-to-use-bluetooth-in-android-emulator) post.
Ideally try to test on a real device.
Concerning the crash, it's better to check the logs (using logcat) so that you get some details where this happens.

Comment: ya...right.Actually first I tried only for connection and it was working properly.But now with read/write code its not working.As I run the App it crashes.Even it is not showing layout on emulator.