# Android phone Bluetooth supports SPP communication or not?

Tags: android, bluetooth, spp

I'm trying to develop an App to receive continuous data from an Bluetooth device which is not an Android.So my question is that Is it possible by android java to do this by programming or do I need to have any SPP supporting software to be installed in Android phone?

Any idea or help regarding this will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes you can 
Android provides [BluetoothSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html) that :

> It is also known as the Serial Port Profile (SPP)

This class offers you two streams (one for reading and one for writing) that you can use to read/write bytes.
Example of opening a socket:

```
BluetoothDevice mBtDevice;
BluetoothSocket mBtSocket;
mBtSocket = mBtDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
mBtSocket.connect();
```

Of course in order to do that the other device must be paired with your phone. After they are paired you can select your device from the list of paired devices provided to you by:

```
BluetoothAdapter    mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply. I've written some code for the same but eclipse giving some problem. If you have some more time,please have glance at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847946/error-on-emulator-of-eclipse