# Bluetooth Low Energy on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluetooth, emulation, bluetooth-lowenergy

I studied about [Bluetooth Low Energy](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html).

But I don't have supported BLE device for testing.

Therefore, I want to ask :

> Do the Android emulator supports BLE feature for testing?

I tried with the following code on **Android Emulator 4.3 (x86) and Android Emulator 4.4 (ARM)**:

```
// Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device. Then
// you can selectively disable BLE-related features.
if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
   Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   finish();
}
```

And it **always show "ble_not_supported"**.

Another question is

> Which another emulator or tool supports BLE for Android?

I really want to test BLE feature on Emulator.

Comment: [The official website](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) says: "Emulator Limitations: ... No support for Bluetooth"

Comment: Really thanks for your comment. But how about "Which another emulator or which another tools has supported BLE for Android?"

Comment: I don't know. MecApp might support BLE, but it's not free, and it's possible that you'll need at least a Bluetooth dongle for your PC with BLE support to use it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Using the Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) said that

> Emulator Limitations
>
> The functional limitations of the emulator include:
>
> No support for placing or receiving actual phone calls. You can simulate phone calls (placed and received) through the emulator console, however.
>
> No support for USB connections
>
> No support for device-attached headphones
>
> No support for determining network connected state
>
> No support for determining battery charge level and AC charging state
>
> No support for determining SD card insert/eject
>
> No support for Bluetooth

Thanks,

Answer (score 25):

It seems you can, using Android inside a VirtualBox and using a PC dongle supporting Bluetooth LE (costs about 18$ on Amazon). Here's the [tutorial by Chris Larson](http://chrislarson.me/blog/emulate-android-and-bluetooth-le-hardware.html) (copied here to keep it online):

> Android emulators are great for developing BluetoothLE applications.
>   The trick is getting the Android emulator to recognize the BluetoothLE
>   adapter.
>
> What you'll need:
>
> - Androidx86 iso from android-x86.org I used the 4.4 release candidate
> - Virtual Machine software: I used Oracle VirtualBox
> - A BluetoothLE USB adapter: I used the Cirago Bluetooth 4.0 USB Mini Adapter (BTA8000)(affilate link) or Cirago Bluetooth 4.0 USB Mini
>     Adapter (BTA8000) (non-affilate link)
> - Install Android SDK for debugging
> - Install VirtualBox
> - Download Androidx86
> - Open VirtualBox and create a new machine. Set type to linux/other(32bit)
> - Set the virtual machine's memory and harddrive space to whatever you need (but at least the minimum specs for Android).
> - When asked for the OS image, select the Androidx86 image you download from Androidx86.org
> - When the virtual machine boots, choose to install Android.
> - When the installation completes, shutdown the Android virtual machine and unmount the iso image
> - Plug in the Bluetooth USB adapter and add it to the Android Virtual Machine's settings
> - Start the Android Virtual Machine and go through the start-up screens to configure Android for use
> - In the Android VM go to the settings and enable BluetoothLE (if this fails reboot the VM and try to enable again)

Here are a few other links describing more or less the same method, and a few other tools that can be of interest to you:

- http://technoga.wordpress.com/2013/05/06/debug-a-bluetooth-app-with-android-emulator-on-pc/
- http://niro-offonatangent.blogspot.fr/2011/06/bluetooth-support-on-android-emulator.html
- http://referenceforu.blogspot.fr/2013/08/testing-bluetooth-in-android-emulator.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2614840/1121352
- https://github.com/cheng81/Android-Bluetooth-Simulator
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magicandroidapps.bluetoothterm&hl=fr
- a set of opensource tools to develop Bluetooth LE apps on Android: https://github.com/grundid/bletools and http://blog.opendatalab.de/hack/2013/11/15/bluetooth-low-energy-tools-library-for-android/

And if you want this issue to be solved by Google, you can star this thread to make it more visible (with enough votes, Google will tackle it in a few years, as they did with audio issues...):

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56608

Comment: Thank you for this guide! I was able to install android this way. Is there a way to run apps from Android studio in this android instance in virtual box? We are developing a BluetoothLE app that we would like to test with BLE hardware his way.

Comment: I don't think there is any compatibility between Android Studio and an Android virtual machine (but you can try to google it), so I guess you will have to compile your app and install it in your VM everytime you want to test it. To automate the process, you can maybe make a post-processing script in Android Studio that would move the compiled APK to your VM using [virtual shared folders](http://www.howtogeek.com/189974/how-to-share-your-computers-files-with-a-virtual-machine/) for example and then [execute your APK in your VM using the VirtualBox API](https://github.com/mjdorma/pyvbox).

Comment: @LukášŠálek you mean running app from Android Studio in a VM?

Answer (score 0):

There is an BLE simulator in

- https://github.com/kwanghoon/emulBLE
  though there is no document available.

This is an Android API level simulator.