# How to use android emulator for testing bluetooth application?

Tags: android

I am developing an application which will send a request to a bluetooth printer for printing. The code is working fine for real devices, but I want to run it on the Android Emulator. How can I use the emulator for bluetooth testing?

Comment: You can not use emulator for bluetooth. And it works on device then why do you want to run it on emulator ?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You can't. The emulator does not support Bluetooth, as mentioned in the SDK's docs and several other places. Android emulator does **not have bluetooth capabilities**".

You can only use real devices.

**Emulator Limitations**

The functional limitations of the emulator include:

- No support for placing or receiving actual phone calls. However, You
  can simulate phone calls (placed and received) through the emulator
  console
- No support for USB
- No support for device-attached headphones
- No support for determining SD card insert/eject
- No support for WiFi, Bluetooth, NFC

Refer to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#starting)

Comment: Recently, there has been this: https://google.github.io/bumble/platforms/android.html

They say they can emulate many Bluetooth protocols; you will need to write the device behavior though.

Answer (score 99):

Download Androidx86 from [this](http://www.android-x86.org/) This is an iso file, so you'd
need something like VMWare or VirtualBox to run it When creating the virtual machine, you need to set the type of guest OS as Linux
instead of Other.

After creating the virtual machine set the network adapter to 'Bridged'. ·
Start the VM and select 'Live CD VESA' at boot.

Now you need to find out the IP of this VM. Go to terminal in VM (use Alt+F1
& Alt+F7 to toggle) and use the netcfg command to find this.

Now you need open a command prompt and go to your android install
folder (on host). This is usually C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>.

Type adb connect IP_ADDRESS. 
There done! Now you need to add Bluetooth. Plug in your USB Bluetooth dongle/Bluetooth device.

In VirtualBox screen, go to Devices>USB devices. Select your dongle.

Done! now your Android VM has Bluetooth. Try powering on Bluetooth and discovering/paring with other devices.

Now all that remains is to go to Eclipse and run your program. The Android AVD manager should show the VM as a device on the list.

Alternatively,  Under settings of the virtual machine, Goto serialports -> Port 1 check Enable serial port select a port number
   then select port mode as disconnected click ok. now, start virtual
   machine. Under Devices -> USB Devices -> you can find your laptop
   bluetooth listed. You can simply check the option and start testing
   the android bluetooth application .

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#EnablingDiscoverability)

Comment: Installing Android in a generic emulator like VirtualBox should work, I have seen this method described several times on various places on the net.

Comment: source seems to be http://niro-offonatangent.blogspot.fr/2011/06/bluetooth-support-on-android-emulator.html

Comment: yes that too and this one http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#EnablingDiscoverability

Comment: What if the host computer has a built-in BLE? Would it be possible to use that instead of the dongle from USB?

Comment: @mr5: If ordinary applications that use Bluetooth can use the chipset, you should be good to go. I'm not sure if BLE and "computer has a bluetooth transceiver in it" are semantically different.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! Worked in the free VMWare player. For step 3, the IP address can also be looked up in Settings -> About phone -> Status (scroll down). `netcfg` wasn't found on my install, though `ifconfig eth0` did the trick.

Comment: How would you install an APK on such a VM?

Comment: @derHugo over the adb i guess. `adb connect 192.168.178.182` then `adb install apk`

Comment: I can ping the VM address, but when i try to adb connect, it says that it cannot connect because the target computer denied access. What can i do?

Answer (score 11):

It seems this has changed recently and they are now supporting Bluetooth as well in emulators with new API versions & google play services.

I'm using API level 32 with google play services to create emulators.

[image]

Comment: But how do you pair it with a real device? On my side the beacons are also visible, but it doesn't seem to detect the real bluetooth devices.

Comment: Nope, can't pair it with real device. It is called [Virtual Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#emulated-bluetooth) for testing purpose.

Comment: You can now connect to physical devices :) The experimental software from google called [Bumble](https://github.com/google/bumble) is a promising tool for this.

Answer (score 8):

Now, in Android Studio 2022.1.1 (Electric eel) you **can** connect with Bluetooth between 2 emulators.
[Official docs from Google](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#emulated-bluetooth).

Comment: The link now points to new releases. Found the original on [waybackmachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20220621050532/https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#emulated-bluetooth)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answer is wrong. The documentation you linked to seems to only indicate that you can test pairing with some mock bluetooth device. Not connect between emulators.

Comment: You can now communicate with other BLE emulated devices over the GRPC server and the [android-netsim](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/netsim/) protocol. A clear example of this is the experimental software from google called [Bumble](https://github.com/google/bumble) which allows to create virtual hci interfaces and connect to android and many more interfaces...

Answer (score 2):

For Android Automotive there is a guide written here: https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/start/passthrough#bluetooth

But it involves editing your kernel to activate bluetooth, and they testesd it with some USB Dongles only, but maybe worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Now, there is a solution using this: https://github.com/google/bumble

It allows you to emulate a Bluetooth stack, and it integrates with the Android emulator: https://google.github.io/bumble/platforms/android.html

Answer (score 0):

Emulator not support Bluetooth, But you can simulate turning it on and off, that's all, Won't have a bluetooth connection working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Actually we cannot run the Bluetooth service on the emulator. It requires the Bluetooth hardware support but the Emulator runs locally within the studio application which cannot access the system hardware.
So the only way is to test the application on a mobile device.