# How to test bluetooth application on android emulator?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am new in android development. I want to know that is it possible to use android emulator for bluetooth applications testing.

Thanks You.

Comment: Just check this link it will help you for your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604305/how-to-use-android-emulator-for-testing-bluetooth-application

Comment: Emulators don't support bluetooth

Comment: Just read this documentation http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#starting