# How to pass data from a background Service/thread and get notification for it?

Tags: android, bluetooth

**Console.class:**

```
public class Console extends Activity  implements Handler.Callback{
    /**
     *  @version 1.1 (28.01.2013)
     *  http://english.cxem.net/arduino/arduino5.php
     *  @author Koltykov A.V. (ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½.ï¿½.)
     * 
     */

    // Store the current connected Device Address;

      private static final String TAG = "bluetooth2";

      Button btnOn, btnOff;
      TextView txtArduino;
      Handler h;

      final static int RECIEVE_MESSAGE = 1;     // Status  for Handler
      private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
      private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
      private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();



      // SPP UUID service
      private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

      // MAC-address of Bluetooth module (you must edit this line)
    //  private static String address = "20:13:03:05:08:07";
      String mCurrentDeviceAddress = null;
        // Name of the connected device
        ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
        SharedPreferences settings;
        // private String bufferMessege;

        // Local Bluetooth adapter
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
      /** Called when the activity is first created. */

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_console);



        settings = getSharedPreferences(DeviceList.PREFS_NAME, 0);

        mCurrentDeviceAddress = settings.getString(
            DeviceList.PREFS_DEVICE_ADDR, null);




        btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOn);                  // button LED ON
        btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOff);                // button LED OFF
        txtArduino = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtArduino);      // for display the received data from the Arduino

        h = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // if receive massage
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 // create string from bytes array
                    sb.append(strIncom);                                                // append string
                    int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // if end-of-line,
                        String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // extract string
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear
                        txtArduino.setText("Data from Arduino: " + sbprint);            // update TextView
                        btnOff.setEnabled(true);
                        btnOn.setEnabled(true); 
                    }
                    //Log.d(TAG, "...String:"+ sb.toString() +  "Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
                    break;
                }
            };
        };

        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
        checkBTState();

        btnOn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            btnOn.setEnabled(false);
            mConnectedThread.write("1");    // Send "1" via Bluetooth
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        });

        btnOff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            btnOff.setEnabled(false);  
            mConnectedThread.write("0");    // Send "0" via Bluetooth
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn off LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        });
      }

      private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
          if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
              try {
                  final Method  m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
                  return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
              }
          }
          return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
      }

      @Override
      public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
       // registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(aa.NOTIFICATION));
        Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

        // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mCurrentDeviceAddress);

        // Two things are needed to make a connection:
        //   A MAC address, which we got above.
        //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
        //     UUID for SPP.

        try {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
        }

        /*try {
          btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
        }*/

        // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
        // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
        Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
        try {
          btSocket.connect();
          Log.d(TAG, "....Connection ok...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
          try {
            btSocket.close();
          } catch (IOException e2) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
          }
        }

        // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
        Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
      }
      @Override
      public void onStart() {
           ((MyApplication)getApplication()).setCallBack(this);
        }
      @Override
      public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ((MyApplication)getApplication()).setCallBack(null);

        Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

        try     {
          btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
          errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
        }
      }

      private void checkBTState() {
        // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
        // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
        if(btAdapter==null) { 
          errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
        } else {
          if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
          } else {
            //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
          }
        }
      }

      private void errorExit(String title, String message){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
      }
```

**ConnectedThread.class:**

```
       class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
            private final InputStream mmInStream;
            private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

            public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
                InputStream tmpIn = null;
                OutputStream tmpOut = null;

                // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
                // member streams are final
                try {
                    tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                    tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) { }

                mmInStream = tmpIn;
                mmOutStream = tmpOut;
            }

            public void run() {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
                int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

                // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        // Read from the InputStream
                        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
                        h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();     // Send to message queue Handler
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
            public void write(String message) {
                Log.d(TAG, "...Data to send: " + message + "...");
                byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
                try {
                    mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "...Error data send: " + e.getMessage() + "...");     
                  }
            }
        }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

**MyApplication.class:**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application  {

    Handler.Callback realCallback = null;
    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if (realCallback != null) {
                realCallback.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        };
    };
    public Handler getHandler() {
        return handler;
    }
    public void setCallBack(Handler.Callback callback) {
        this.realCallback = callback;
    }
}
```

**aa.class:**

```
public class aa extends Service {


    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    public static final String BT_DEVICE = "btdevice";
    public static final String SPP_UUID = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0; // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1; // now listening for incoming
                                                // connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing
                                                    // connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3; // now connected to a remote
                                                    // device
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private static ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    // public mInHangler mHandler = new mInHangler(this);
    private static Handler mHandler = null;
    public static int mState = STATE_NONE;
    public static String deviceName;
    public Vector<Byte> packdata = new Vector<Byte>(2048);
    public static BluetoothDevice device = null;
    SharedPreferences settings;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("PrinterService", "Service started");
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        mHandler = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getHandler();
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        aa getService() {
            return aa.this;
        }
    }



    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("PrinterService", "Onstart Command");
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        settings = getSharedPreferences(DeviceList.PREFS_NAME, 0);

        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {

        //    device = (Device) intent.getSerializableExtra(BT_DEVICE);
       //     deviceName = device.getDeviceName();
            String macAddress = settings.getString(
                    DeviceList.PREFS_DEVICE_ADDR, null);
            device =   mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
            if (macAddress != null && macAddress.length() > 0) {
                connectToDevice(macAddress);
            } else {
                stopSelf();
                return 0;
            }
        }
        String stopservice = intent.getStringExtra("stopservice");
        if (stopservice != null && stopservice.length() > 0) {
            stop();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private synchronized void connectToDevice(String macAddress) {
        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {
                mConnectThread.cancel();
                mConnectThread = null;
            }
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    private void setState(int state) {
        aa.mState = state;
        if (mHandler != null) {
      //      mHandler.obtainMessage(AbstractActivity.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        setState(STATE_NONE);
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        setState(STATE_NONE);
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        return super.stopService(name);
    }

    private void connectionFailed() {
        aa.this.stop();
      //  Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Console.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        //bundle.putString(Console.TOAST, "zeft");
        //msg.setData(bundle);
        //mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    private void connectionLost() {
        aa.this.stop();
      //  Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(AbstractActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    //    bundle.putString(AbstractActivity.TOAST, getString(R.string.error_connect_lost));
        //msg.setData(bundle);
     //   mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    private static Object obj = new Object();

    public static void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (obj) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED)
                return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }

    private synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket mmSocket, BluetoothDevice mmDevice) {
        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        // Message msg =
        // mHandler.obtainMessage(AbstractActivity.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        // Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        // bundle.putString(AbstractActivity.DEVICE_NAME, "p25");
        // msg.setData(bundle);
        // mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);

    }
```

**ConnectThread.class:**

```
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            this.mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(SPP_UUID));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            setName("ConnectThread");
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            try {
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                connectionFailed();
                return;

            }
            synchronized (aa.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("PrinterService", "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Printer Service", "temp sockets not created", e);
            }
            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
             byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
                int bytes ;
            while (true) {
                try {
                     bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);   
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(Console.RECIEVE_MESSAGE,
                     bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    connectionLost();
                    aa.this.stop();
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

        private byte[] btBuff;


        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);

                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(Console.RECIEVE_MESSAGE, buffer.length, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("PrinterService", "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("PrinterService", "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }

    }

    public void trace(String msg) {
        Log.d("AbstractActivity", msg);
        toast(msg);
    }

    public void toast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stop();
        Log.d("Printer Service", "Destroyed");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void sendMsg(int flag) {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = flag;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {//
            if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                case 3:

                    break;

                case 4:

                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;

                case -1:
                    break;
                }
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }

    };


}
```

Comment: what is the wrong of my code ??

Comment: Whats the problem you are facing?

Comment: the application stop after connecting with Bluetooth device

Comment: In that case paste the logs of the error

Comment: The application dose not work on the emulator
so I don't know where is the error

Comment: Connect to your physical device and get the logs. I don't think without logs its possible to know whats wrong.

Comment: android.app.application cannot be cast to ....MyApplication

Answer (score 0):

With regards to

> How to pass data from a background Service/thread and get notification
>   for it?

I believe the Android AsyncTask was designed for that, but you need to use it correctly as it is often misunderstood, especially handling the full lifecycle of an app.

As to why your code is not working, as Ranjith said we need more specifics.

To run bluetooth in an emulator try a VM and USB dongle:

[How to use android emulator for testing bluetooth application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604305/how-to-use-android-emulator-for-testing-bluetooth-application)