# I'm trying to run bluetooth chat app in android studio emulator...but am unable

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to run Bluetooth chat app in android studio emulator...but am unable.Please let me know if I can run it on any other software emulator.
How to run a genymotion plugin for this application project

Comment: Android emulator does not support this by default . But there is a work around. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604305/how-to-use-android-emulator-for-testing-bluetooth-application/22604411#22604411 & http://niro-offonatangent.blogspot.in/2011/06/bluetooth-support-on-android-emulator.html

Answer (score 1):

I think android studio emulator does not support bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

**Android Emulators are not real devices.You can not use bluetooth,Wifi etc.. functionalities like you do in real devices.**

So you better try running your App on a real device not Emulator.