# Android emulator that supports Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-emulator, android-bluetooth, dongle

Do you guys know of an Android emulator that supports Bluetooth?

If none, then are there any that can use a Bluetooth USB dongle?

Comment: I am also developing an app with BT, unfortunately, the Android studio emulator does not support BT. You should use real device. As also discussed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604305/how-to-use-android-emulator-for-testing-bluetooth-application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use android emulator for testing bluetooth application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604305/how-to-use-android-emulator-for-testing-bluetooth-application)

Comment: That was a while ago, so maybe something new came out.

Comment: Also, I didn't specify the Android Studio emulator. I was asking if there were any other emulators out there that support Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

Android emulator does not have bluetooth capabilities, as mentioned in the SDK's docs and several other places

Refer to this documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#starting