# Bluetooth on Android emulator

Tags: android, bluetooth

Basically, when I was initially developing a Bluetooth Android app, I was able with my desktop PC to "enable" the Bluetooth. Instead on my laptop as soon as I executed `bluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` I got a crash. Now I'm retrying for the sake of error reporting and I've got this error with no crash:

> E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null

I ask the user to enable the bt on the app's opening, and if he refuses the app shuts down, instead if he accepts I use the Android's intent for the bt activation and I wait for the user to enable it.
If I click yes on the first dialog it keeps showing infinitely when executing in my laptop's emualtor, instead if I press `no`, the app is closed.

When I was in the PC emulator I was able to get a non-NULL value from `getDefaultAdapter()` and do some basic testing, instead, when executing on the laptop, I get `NULL`. I know is NOT possible to make two emulators connect each other via Bluetooth (from [How to use android emulator for testing bluetooth application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604305/how-to-use-android-emulator-for-testing-bluetooth-application)), but would be handy to use the emulator for other app's features beside Bluetooth without having each time to wire up my phone.