# How to share released app on emulator to physical device in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I was building app on my physical device and suddenly their occurred some problem with USB connector in my phone. So I was compelled to use emulator. But my urgent need is test bluetooth thermal printer and emulators don't provide bluetooth services as per this [How to use android emulator for testing bluetooth application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604305/how-to-use-android-emulator-for-testing-bluetooth-application) answer. So is there any way that I build or release on an emulator and could share its **APK** to my physical device?

Answer (score 0):

You won't get Bluetooth functionalities on an emulator.  The emulator does not support Bluetooth.

You need to create an apk using `flutter build apk` command and later can transfer that apk to your device.

Comment: How to transfer that apk to my device is my question...

Comment: use some normal file transfer operation. you can find the built apk inside build folder. use your USB cable or email or anything