# Adding Bluetooth Devices to Android Emulator (AVD)

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-virtual-device

how can I add additional devices like the gDevice Beacons to the AVD? Is that possible?

[Bluetooth devices on AVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqC6Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth on Android emulator is pretty strange. There are a lot questions about it with answers, that bluetooth is not supported on emulator.

But there are also several mentions, that it is supported. Like here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71912351/10475643

I tried several images and beacons were really appeared on image with API 32. But not appeared on 33 and 34. But even on 32 I found them pretty useless, because it is not clear how to pair with them. If one tap on them - "Pairing" message is displayed and after one minute disappears without real pairing.

There is also a tool Bubble https://google.github.io/bumble/platforms/android.html, which is suppose to emulate real devices or bridge emulator with them. But I didn't tried that.