# OnHoverListener is not working on an android emulator?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-emulator, mouseover, event-listener

I'm trying to add mouse/touchpad support to my app and that includes hover support. [As per the android guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/input-compatibility-large-screens), which say:

> Developers can make their app layouts feel polished and easier to use by handling hover events. This is especially true for custom views. The two most common examples of this are:
>
> - Indicating to users if an element has interactive behavior, such as being clickable or editable, by changing the mouse pointer icon.
> - Adding visual feedback to items in a large list or grid when the pointer is hovering over them

```
yourView.setOnHoverListener { view, _ ->
  addVisualHighlighting(true)
  view.pointerIcon =
    PointerIcon.getSystemIcon(view.context,
    PointerIcon.TYPE_HAND)
  false // listener did not consume the event.
}
```

This is not working e.g. the pointer icon is not changing and a debug/print line is NOT being called, at least not on an emulator. I am unable to test on a real device so could this be a limitation of the android emulator or am I wrongly implementing this listener? Would it run correctly on the Windows 11 subsystem for android?

Comment: How are you connecting a mouse to the emulated device? Moving the mouse pointer across the emulator window isn't the same as connecting an input device to Android, and I'm pretty sure you'd need to do that - not sure how you'd do it though! I don't think you can use Bluetooth on the emulator to connect one. All the recommendations I've seen for that involve downloading an Android x86 image and creating a VM on your computer (at which point you can probably just use your mouse directly in the VM)

Comment: @cactustictacs ahh I could try that. Would that mean installing a third party emulator like BlueStacks?

Comment: I'm only going off what I got from a quick search - there's an answer here describing it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22604411/13598222 it's old but I'd imagine the process is the same, use some Virtual Machine software (maybe Hyper-V in Windows if it's available) to create a virtual Android device that can directly access your keyboard, mouse, bluetooth etc. One of the other answers on there points out that the official Emulator doesn't have virtual Bluetooth support (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#limitations) but other emulators might!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I tried running my app on android x86 in VirtualBox and everything worked! Looks like the android studio emulator doesn't capture mouse pointers. I'm only wondering if this will work on the Windows 11 subsystem.