# Android Studio Bluetooth Adapter

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth

I've been trying to implement the startDiscover() function on a project in Android Studio based on Bluetooth. I have implemented a button to start discovering but however, it doesn't work. The Logcat is also not showing any errors to try to rectify.

When the discover button is clicked it should display the list of available bluetooth devices nearby.

Comment: Do you mean you tried your app in the Emulator provided by Android Studio? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604305/how-to-use-android-emulator-for-testing-bluetooth-application