# Bluetooth Advertisements are not supported on this device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using Bluetooth Advertisements from this https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples repository.

uses-preferences and uses-feature are in the AndroidManifest.
But still it is shown that "Bluetooth Advertisements are not supported on this device".

[MainActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AYL3.png)
[AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y641B.png)

Edit: I'm using the Android emulator at the time, but want to use a physical device in the future.

Edit 2: Trying with my private phone. It still says "Bluetooth Advertisements are not supported on this device".

Comment: Are you using the Android emulator or a physical device for testing?

Comment: I'm using the Android emulator.

Comment: Ah, there's your problem right there - Wrote an answer addressing both emulator and physical device problems. It's possible your phone just doesn't support bluetooth advertisements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android Emulator does not support Bluetooth, as mentioned in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/advanced-emulator-usage):

> **Limitations**
>
> The Android Emulator doesn't include virtual hardware for the
> following:
>
> - Bluetooth
> - NFC
> - SD card insert/eject
> - Device-attached headphones
> - USB

On a physical device - Make sure your phone supports Bluetooth 5 features required for BLE advertising by using methods from [BluetoothAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html) such as `isLeExtendedAdvertisingSupported()` to check. For more details see [this documentation page](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/bluetooth/ble_advertising).

There may be a workaround available - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4983743/5697347) about using Android-x86 in VMWare that may work for you, although I will caution that it may not support the very latest Android APIs as it seems Android-x86 hasn't been updated in over a year.